# Issues with JTable at JTree node

Tags: java, jtable, jtree

I'm trying to create a `JTable` at a node of a `JTree`. I have several issues with the below implementation:

- The user is not able to interact (select cells) with the `JTree` for some reason.
- If I put the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`, scrolling does not work. The `JTree` I'm implementing is also in a `JScrollPane` so there could be some interference there (#scrollception).
- I am not able to customize the dimensions of the table
- The titles of the table are only present if implemented in a `JScrollPane`

Could you kindly help me resolve these issues.

**JTable in node**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

public class ExampleRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    private Map<String, JTable> tables = new HashMap<String, JTable>();

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        if (value.toString().startsWith("TABLE:")) {
            c = tables.get(value.toString());

            if (c == null) {
                JTable table = new JTable(createModel(value.toString()));

                //table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

                //JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

                tables.put(value.toString(), table);
                c = tables.get(value.toString());
            }
        }

        return c;
    }

    private TableModel createModel(String tableData) {
        tableData = tableData.substring(6, tableData.length());

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        String[] colData = tableData.split("¬");

        for (String data : colData) {
            String[] components = data.split("=");
            model.addColumn(components[0], components[1].split(","));
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

**Example implementation**

```
public ExampleJTreeWithJTable() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Example");
    root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("TABLE:Column A=Cell 1.1,Cell 2.1,Cell 3.1¬Column B=Cell 1.2,Cell 2.2,Cell 3.2"));

    JTree tree = new JTree(root);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new ExampleRenderer());

    add(tree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
}
```

Comment: First of all, have a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).  Second of all, consider something like `JXTreeTable` instead

Comment: Or [`Outline`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline).